# PyQt5 QListView sluggish first drag/drop on windows - python 3.5/3.4 32bit, pyqt5 from sourceforge

Tags: python, windows, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I have installed 32bit Python 3.4 and 3.5 and PyQt5 on our windows 7 work machine via the executable available from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/, however I now find that when I run my simple drag and drop test code it is very sluggish moving the first element (the ui freezes for about 4-5 seconds before completing the move). All subsequent drag and drop operations happen without that delay.

By "ui freezes" I mean that the selection remains highlit and in its original place when i move the cursor away and the drag and drop guide graphics (a line appearing where the items would move to if i let the mouse button go at that time, the mouse cursor changing to a different icon to indicate that drag and drop is occuring) do not appear. If I release the mouse button during this time the selected elements are moved to that location but not until the 4-5 second wait time has elapsed.

The code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QListView, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

def createModel():
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    for i in range(0,101): 
        item = QStandardItem(str(i))
        item.setText(str(i))
        item.setEditable(False)
        item.setDropEnabled(False)
        model.appendRow(item)
    return model

class TestListView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listView = QListView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.listView)
        self.listView.setModel(createModel())
        self.listView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.listView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.listView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    lvt = TestListView()
    lvt.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am hoping someone can point out a foolish mistake I've made that is the cause of this issue (like when I earlier had passed ints to the QStandardItems constructor instead of strings, resulting in a crash each time I tried to drag and drop), but if that isn't the case, if anyone is able to recommend a combination of pyqt5 and 32bit (64bit is not an option for us) python components that they've found that does not exhibit this behaviour? I don't really care if it's python 3.x or python 2.x (although I haven't seen any pyqt5/python2 combinations previously), as long as it works.

I've tried the python-qt5 package that pip installs (after following the instructions here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/ by installing visual c++ build tools) in both 3.4 and 3.5, but the full version of this script will use .ui files from QtCreator, and the pip version of python-qt5 throws an error:

```
  File "testReorder.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import uic
  File "c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .Compiler import indenter, compiler
  File "c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 43, in <module>
    from ..properties import Properties
  File "c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\properties.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .icon_cache import IconCache
  File "c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\icon_cache.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .port_v3.as_string import as_string
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.uic.port_v3'
```

when I include the import line

```
from PyQt5 import uic
```

in the code.

Edit: Having gotten home and tested the code on my linux machine (and seen no signs of sluggishness), I'm thinking this issue must be either specific to the combination of the pyqt, python and windows version, or something specific to that particular windows installation, and not a problem with my code.

I'd still be interested in hearing of anyone able to run the same code and not see the same issues on a windows (especially windows 7) machine, but I'm thinking it's less likely that I can assign the blame for this behaviour solely at pyqt's door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran same code on another windows 7 computer with same packages installed. The issue is not seen there, so is obviously a problem with something specific to this machine rather than the code I've written/versions of python I'm using/version of pyqt.